# Updated State not being retrieved by method

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

In this file, I'm pulling in a bunch of data from an API and assigning it to the array of "baseData". In another file, I have an onkeyup event calling the generateResults method. But then generateResults method is only getting the original, blank state of the array. I'm new to react so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```html
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export class LINKS extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        baseData: []
}}



    getBaseData(){

        axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/links")
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({baseData: response.data});
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });


 }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.getBaseData();
    }



    generateResults(){
        var linkInfo = this.state.baseData
        var searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar')
        console.log(linkInfo)

        for(var i = 0; i < linkInfo.length; i ++){

        }



    }



render(){
    var linkInfo = this.state.baseData

    // console.log(linkInfo)

    if(linkInfo.length === 0){
        return(
        <div><h1> Loading... </h1></div>)
    } else {

    return(



        <div>{linkInfo.map((info, i) =>
            <div>
            <u>{info['client']}</u>
            {info.links.map((link, i) =>
                <div> {link.linkTitle}
                <br/> {link.url} </div>) }
            <hr/></div>
        )}</div>



        )
}


}
}
```

Method in the other class calling the generateResults method.

```html
  handleSearch(){
    let links = new LINKS
    links.generateResults()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should return any HTML into your arrow function map loop with double Parentheses like this :

```html
<ul>
                    {
                        this.props.items.map((item) => (
                            <li>{item}</li>
                        ))
                    }
</ul>
```

I've edited your code, try this :

```html
<div>
{
  linkInfo.map((info, i) => (
      <div>
      <u>{info['client']}</u>
      {
          info.links.map((link, i) => (
            <div> {link.linkTitle}
            <br/> {link.url} </div>
          ))
      }
      <hr/></div>
  ))
}
</div>
```

Comment: Should have been more clear. The render method works just fine. The divs populate with all the correct information. But the generateResults() method is still using the original state of the array. So when I type into the box that calls that method, it's just returning a blank array instead of the new state.

Comment: @Tom Did you checked your API result ? maybe that doesn't received any data and that is empty ?! and consider it, the generateResults() method doesn't return any variable and that for/loop is empty .... why you are calling that method ? do you have any error in console ?